# error 7-zip running on Powershell script

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I am writing a powershell script to generate backup using the 7-zip, but something is not working. When I run the code below

```
if (-not (test-path "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe")) {throw "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe needed"} 
set-alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"
$BACKUP_DATE = Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d"
$LOCAL_BKP = 'E:\_Bkp_Producao'

New-PSDrive –Name "s" –PSProvider FileSystem –Root "\\server\myfolder"
sz a $LOCAL_BKP\bkp_siemens_$BACKUP_DATE.7z S:\*
```

return the following messages:

```
7-Zip [64] 9.38 beta  Copyright (c) 1999-2014 Igor Pavlov  2015-01-03
Scanning
S:\:  WARNING: The system cannot find the path specified.
Creating archive E:\_Bkp_Producao\bkp_siemens_2015-08-31.7z
WARNINGS for files:
S:\ : The system cannot find the path specified.
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Did you remember to create the `$LOCAL_BKP` folder?

Comment: yes, he already existed (again, the 7z file was created at that location). Thank you.

Comment: Try adding `-Persist` to the `New-PSDrive` command.

Comment: It worked! As my script creates and deletes mapping at the end, I didn't think I would need to use the -Persist. Thank you! Please enter an answer, so I can vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-- Old & Busted Answer --**

I know this is really a duplicate of powershell string interpolation, but I can't find that one right now.

Alternatives that work:

```
$sz = "${env:ProgramFiles}\7-Zip\7z.exe"
$sz = $env:ProgramFiles + "\7-Zip\7z.exe"
$sz = '{0}\7-Zip\7z.exe' -f $env:ProgramFiles
```

You could also try using `Join-Path`, but I find it troublesome.

**-- New Hotness --**

You need to add the `-Persist` option to `New-PSDrive`. If you don't use `-Persist`, the "drive" is only visible to powershell cmdlets. Adding it makes the "drive" available to all commands, including native windows command line applications.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the problem is not the 7-zip (see that it returns the installed version and also creates the 7z file), but to see the sharing.

Comment: You should click the checkmark icon to Accept the answer. Voting doesn't mark it as the accepted answer.